# google cloud dataflow can run locally but can't run on the cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I can't run my pipeline locally, using the "DirectPipelineRunner" but when I use "BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner" to run on the cloud it always shows that "Failed to split source". I don't where is the problem of my pipeline.

I define my custom sources to read a lot of tgz file in my bucket. The following is my code.

```
class My_Compressed_Source(filebasedsource.FileBasedSource):
    def read_records(self, file_name, range_tracker):
        import tarfile
        import re    
        start_offset = range_tracker.start_position()
        with self.open_file(file_name) as f:
            tar = tarfile.open(fileobj = f)            
            for member in tar.getmembers():
            f = tar.extractfile(member)
            content = f.read()                    
            # do some regular expression process to content
```

And here is my pipeline

```
pcoll = p | 'Read' >> beam.Read(My_Compressed_Source(args.input, splittable = False))
pcoll | beam.ParDo('parse tar member', Parse_Members())
p.run()
```

also, my input path of bucket is "--input gs://mybucket/source/*.tgz" and my job-id is "2016-10-14_09_21_43-4409773810679481086".
I am wondering should I set "splittable" to True. Or if there is something wrong.

Comment: Can you try setting 'compression_type=fileio.CompressionTypes.GZIP' when constructing 'My_Compressed_Source' ?

Comment: I tried but still failed the job. Q_Q And it still logged out the same error."Failed to split source"

Comment: I read the code of avro file source from the document example [link]( https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/python-sdk/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py) it seems that `with self.open_file(file_name) as f` the f is not a file_obj is this the correct understanding of the code?

Comment: This error means that Dataflow job failed when trying to split the source into sub-sources within a GCE worker machine. There may be more details about the error in cloud logs. Can you see if there are any error stack traces there ?

See “Viewing Compute Engine Logs for Your Job” section in following link for instructions on accessing cloud logs.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline

Method open_file() should return a file object (or an object that implements the same interface).

Comment: I check the log from dataflow. Here is the log of my job. The part of  exception before the job failed is `line 250, in load obj = pik.load() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load dispatch[key](self) KeyError: 'x'`. I can't paste all of it. I still can't figure out why it can't run successfully.

Comment: Dataflow uses Python dill module to pickle source objects and then unpickle them at GCE workers. Seems like a GCE worker failed to unpickle your source object and it's not clear to my why this happened. Is there any extra state that you store in your source object that is not shown in the above code segment ? Can you also try doing a dill.loads(dill.dumps(source_object)) to see if 'dill' module can properly pickle/unpickle your source object ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading a tar file using StringIO as mentioned above cannot be recommended due to having to load all data into memory.

Seems like your original implementation didn't work since tarfile.open() using methods seek() and tell() which are not supported by fileio._CompressedFile object returned by filebasedsource.open_file().

I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-778 for this.

Comment: At last I use an alternative way to solve my problem. Instead of reading source directly from the source, I ask dataflow to read a filename list which is a plain text file. And use api to get compressed file from bucket to workers. But I am wondering if the way is encouraged, if not then what consequence will it have

Comment: Are you using FileBasedSoure for this ? If so please do either (1) implement dynamic work rebalancing properly (for example, see textio._TextSource.read()) OR (2) disable splitting files into data ranges (splittable=False). Otherwise you could run into issues due to Dataflow performing work rebalancing based on byte positions . (2) should be enough if file containing file-names is not large. Additionally you might want to introduce a GroupByKey right after reading file names so that the process of reading files is distributed across workers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments above.
I tried several ways to solve my problem. And I have a little progress. I think it is necessary that I should describe my problem again.

I add the compression_type argument and set it to `fileio.CompressionTypes.GZIP`. Just as below.

```
pcoll = p | "Read" >> beam.io.Read(My_Compressed_Source(args.input, split = False, compression_type = fileio.CompressionTypes.GZIP))
pcoll | beam.ParDo('parse tar member', Parse_Members())
p.run()
```

I try to execute it locally through "DirectPipelineRunner", and tarfile.open() showed an error. So I modified my read_records function to the below version.

```
class My_Compressed_Source(filebasedsource.FileBasedSource):
    def read_records(self, file_name, range_tracker):
    import tarfile
    import re
    import StringIO
    start_offset = range_tracker.start_position()
    f = self.open_file(file_name)
    start = range_tracker.start_position
    text_str = str(f.read(f._read_size))
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(text_str), bufsize=f._read_size)
    for mem in tar.getmembers():
        print mem.name
```

I specify the number of bytes for f.read() to get the whole content of my tgz file. And now the files are just tar. 
And then I use StringIO module to create a temporary file_obj to put in tarfile.open. Finally I used a loop to access each name of the file. I indeed extract some file name but just a few of files are accessed.

After trying different data source, I think the key is no matter which the source is, the length of f._read_size is always has a maximum 16384 = 16k. I wonder If there is some where to set the maximum of buffer size can let me access whole content, or I should try another way?